# Ios Firebase asynchronous LogIn

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous

How to deal with an asynchronous query without "`DispatchQueue`" See below:

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){}
```

This is example firebase login

[LogInViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC5dr.png)

[FirebaseLogIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTAn1.png)

Comment: Please include your code as code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `FirebaseLogIn` file you've actually already created a `DataSentDelegateLogIn` delegate which will do exactly what you're looking for—and you've implemented it correctly in the `FirebaseLogIn` class in the `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn` callback. This is great—now you just have to implement your delegate method in your `LogInViewController`.

In `LogInViewController`, move `FirebaseLog.delegate = self` into your `viewDidLoad()` method, and remove all of the `Dispatch` code from your `logInBTN(_ sender: Any)` function. Then, implement the `userEnterData(data: Bool)` delegate method in the `LogInViewController`:

```
func userEnterData(data: Bool) {
    if data
        // handle successful login
    else {
        // handle unsuccessful login
    }
}
```

A brief primer on delegates, [from this great explaination by James Rochabrun](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef):

> Delegates are a design pattern that allows one object to send messages to another object when a specific event happens.

So when `FirebaseLogIn` calls the `userEnterData` delegate method, it's the implementation in the `LogInViewController` that gets called. Neat!

(And please copy your code into your question as code and not screenshots next time you ask a question on Stack Overflow. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code to `userEnterData` method instead.
And set the delegate before calling `logIn`.